# Check if node contains value XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<Reply>
  <OptionInfoReply>
    <Option>
       <Opt>EDIFBEB </Opt>
       <OptAvail>-3 </OptAvail>
    </Option>
    <Option>
       <Opt>CHSFBEB </Opt>
       <OptAvail>-3 </OptAvail>
    </Option>
    <Option>
       <Opt>WESFBEB </Opt>
       <OptAvail>-3 </OptAvail>
   </Option>
```

And anthoer XML which I used in for each :

```
<Reply>
  <OptionInfoReply>
    <Option>
      <Opt>CHSFBEB</Opt>
    </Option>
  </OptionInfoReply>
</Reply>
```

I'm moving in for each on the second xml. I want to check  if the value of CHSFBEB from the second XML exists in the first xml.

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Reply/OptionInfoReply/Option">
        <xsl:variable name="SearchOPT"  select="Opt"/>
        <db:AVAILABLE_ROOMS_NO>
         <xsl:value-of      select="$AVL/Reply/OptionInfoReply/Option/Opt[contains(.,$SearchOPT)]/../OptAvail"/>
        </db:AVAILABLE_ROOMS_NO>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

However, if in the first XML I have more than one option, I don't get the value of OptAvail (from the first xml). If I have only one node I will receive the value from OptAvail.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It might be a good idea to further simplify your code: Remove anything that is irrelevant, such as (I’m guessing) all the `db:` elements in the output. Making your question easy to read means more and better answers for you, in general. And don’t forget to explain what you mean by “not working.”

Comment: In your current example, you do have "more than one option" in the first XML, but your XSLT will work as expected (in that it returns -3). Or is it the case, you may have "CHSFBEB" appearing more than once in the first XML? If so, can you show an example of this, and the output you expect? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:MyUtils="pda:MyUtils">
  <xsl:template match="/">
   <check>
   <xsl:variable name="second" select="MyUtils:getSecondXMLData()//Opt"/>
   <xsl:for-each select="//Option">
     <xsl:if test="Opt=$second">
      <AVAILABLE_ROOMS_NO>
        <xsl:value-of select="OptAvail"/>
      </AVAILABLE_ROOMS_NO>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
   </check>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I haven't fetched the second xml via document function. That part is done via extension function "getSecondXMLData()" which gives a set of nodes from the second xml.
I have assumed your first xml to be like this:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <Reply>
     <OptionInfoReply>
       <Option>
         <Opt>EDIFBEB</Opt>
          <OptAvail>-3</OptAvail>
       </Option>
    <Option>
      <Opt>CHSFBEB</Opt>
      <OptAvail>-3 </OptAvail>
    </Option>
    <Option>
      <Opt>WESFBEB</Opt>
      <OptAvail>-3 </OptAvail>
    </Option>
    <Option>
      <Opt>CHSFBEB</Opt>
      <OptAvail>-3 </OptAvail>
    </Option>
  </OptionInfoReply>
</Reply>
```

Kindly note that your first xml contains blank spaces which need to removed before comparison can actualy be done